# jquery ui sortable elements stop sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sorting

I think this may have something to do with a .live() like issue. 
At one point I have an option where a user can select something and the sortable list gets animated off screen then the elements .remove() from the DOM. But then in the same hand I have an option to bring it back in, and I rebuild it into the page. At that point I lose the sort ability. Its worth mentioning that the initial loading of the elements is through jquery. So they aren't static elements when the page renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i were to take a guess then i think that the event bindings are lost when you remove elements from the list. Try running 
`$('yourlist').sortable()` again after you populate the list.

Comment: that was the issue, upon remove() it was losing its ability to sort. Reapplying the sorable() after reload patched the problem.